# Different ways of Usage of word "sarcastic" to represent a person who is sarcastic

Tags: word-usage

If I met a person who is sarcastic,  is it correct if I say that the person is having a "sarcastic inside"  where inside means brain or soul

Comment: No, that would not be idiomatic.  Al person’s insides usually refers to their guts/internal organs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because beyond answering "No" there's nothing else here. And a question which elicits single word answers isn't a good one for this site.

Answer (score 0):

It is not idiomatic to refer to the 'insides' when speaking of dispositions. But it is idiomatic to refer to '**the interior**' in such a case :

> a. Belonging to or existing in the mind or soul; mental or spiritual, as distinguished from that which is bodily; ‘inward’:

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97831?redirectedFrom=interior#eid)